# Xubuntu - missing checkbox "connect VPN automatically"

Tags: xubuntu, network-manager, vpn

I'm trying to make my VPN connect automatically (on startup or when I got disconnected from Wifi) and most of users have a checkbox directly in network-manager. I don't.

I thought I have old network-manager but synaptic doesn't see network-manager as upgradeable.

Of course I found vpnautoconnect and some scripts but there is no standard way how to keep VPN connected in Xubuntu 14.04?

Thank you.

Comment: However I have found (only when VPN is present) that checkbox "Automatically connect to VPN when using this connection" appeared in Wifi connection settings. It won't reconnect you when VPN is down but at least will start at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to somebody else:

I missed an option in Xubuntu Network Manager when editing some ethernet / WiFi connection - in general tab a VPN can be specified and it's gonna connect automatically on that network.

It's not in the VPN settings directly.